# How can I get all the rows of my table and display it in an alert message?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello everyone I was wondering how i could retrieve all rows of my table. I would like to have an alert message popping up showing the rows and all the data within it.

**here is my table code**

```
      <table id="adminTable" class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm table-hover">
             <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
                  <br>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Emailaddress</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Admin</th>
                        <th>BHV'er</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                     <tbody id="myTable">
                        <tr class="table">
                            <td class="table">email</td>
                            <td class="table">name</td>
                            <td class="table">
                                <form>
                                    <select id="isAdmin">
                                        <option selected>false</option>
                                        <option value="false">false</option>
                                        <option value="true">true</option>
                                    </select>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            <td class="table">bhv</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
               </table>
                <button type="button" onclick="onSubmit()" class="btn btnprimary">Submit</button>
```

**This is what I have gotten so far**

```
function onSubmit() {
        var table = document.getElementById('adminTable');
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
        {
            alert( i + " row : " + rows[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
```

**This is the output in the alert box which for some reason is an entire piece of code**
[image: This is the output in the alert box]

Comment: I have added my attempt of retrieving the rows. thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Ok, so now what are expected results? I doubt you actually want innerHTML but that is not specified. Presumably you would want some sort of array structure. It is incumbent on you to provide such details rather than a vague "row data" term

Comment: Side note: `<input>` is invalid child of `<table>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following is of some help to you:

```js
onSubmit=()=>alert([...document.querySelectorAll("#adminTable tbody tr")]
  .map(tr=>[...tr.children].map(td=>{
    let s=td.querySelector('select');
    return s && s.value || td.textContent })
  .join(',')).join('\n'))
```

```html
<input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search.."><br>
<table id="adminTable" class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm table-hover">
             
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Emailaddress</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Admin</th>
                        <th>BHV'er</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                     <tbody id="myTable">
                        <tr class="table">
                            <td class="table">email</td>
                            <td class="table">name</td>
                            <td class="table">
                                <form>
                                    <select id="isAdmin">
                                        <option selected>false</option>
                                        <option value="false">false</option>
                                        <option value="true">true</option>
                                    </select>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            <td class="table">bhv</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
               </table>
<button type="button" onclick="onSubmit()" class="btn btnprimary">Submit</button>
```

I moved your input element to a position where it will result in valid HTML.

Feel free to change the column (`,`) in line separators (`\n`) in the line `.join(',')).join('\n'))` to something you like.

Comment: Is there a way to leave the tr elements of the thead out of the result?

Comment: That can be easily achieved by changing the initial selector to `"#adminTable tbody tr"`, see my updated answer.